# Redirect login page to main app page with CSRF token PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, csrf

I have a login page (login.php) that redirects to my main page (dashboard.php). When the user POSTs their email and password to login.php I validate credentials, create a CSRF token, store it in the session, and then redirect to dashboard.php.  Upon redirection, however, dashboard.php is doing it's own validation of the session and CSRF token. Since it's a redirect in php, I cannot attach any custom headers to contain the CSRF and dashboard.php is redirecting back to login.php. I thought I may be able to handle this with JavaScript but haven't found any examples of redirecting to another page in JavaScript and including the CSRF token in a header. I know I could redirect with a GET variable using the CSRF token but that seems insecure.

Login.php

```
<?php 
$user = new AuthenticatedUser($dbh);
$loggedIn = $user->isLoggedIn();
if ($user->isLoggedIn())
{
    header("Location: dashboard.php");
    die("Redirecting to dashboard...");
}

if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
{
    $user->login($_POST["email"], $_POST["password"]);

    if ($user->isLoggedIn())
    {
        header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }
}
```

dashboard.php

```
<?php
$dbh = new Database();
$authUser = new AuthenticatedUser($dbh);

// When constructing the AuthenticatedUser class object in dashboard.php the
// constructor function checks to see if the user has a session and if so then
// checks for the CSRF is set. If it's not the class flips the flag for
// isLoggedIn which in turn tells dashboard.php to redirect back to login.php
if (!$authUser->isLoggedIn())
{
    header("Location: login.php");
    die("Redirecting to login...");
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this for academic purposes, or for production use?

Comment: Ehh seems like a loaded question but this will eventually be for production use. @tadman

Comment: This is a dangerous road to go down. There's a lot of [threats you'll need to protect against](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) and doing this in a homebrew PHP system is difficult, time consuming, and risky.  If you're developing a serious application you should be using a development framework to give you a secure foundation. These come in a variety of forms, from very light-weight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to very full-featured like 
[Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: While you're obviously trying to do the right thing here, which is commendable, you're exposing a lot of internals that, to an attacker, are extremely informative. `login.php` usually screams "come and get it!" to anyone looking for a vector to attack. Frameworks go out of their way to obscure this kind of information using a routing layer so attack vectors are less obvious, and there's an opportunity to screen for common forms of abuse consistently across all requests.

Comment: @tadman I appreciate the advice, I have looked into OWASP best practices  and as far as I know have handled them. I could definitely be naive/shallow in my security practices. Is there one or a couple in particular that is jumping out to you with this approach I am using?

Comment: I like what you're doing here, but as good as you might be at handling this you're eventually going to make a mistake, and tiny mistakes are often punished severely by attackers. Consider this: If you use a popular framework then, should a security bug be found you're unlikely to be the first person impacted by it. You can probably patch and be safe. On your own framework you absolutely will be the first impacted by it, you'll have to patch *and* clean up the mess, if it can even be cleaned up at all. You can't un-breach your database...

Comment: As with many things in development, doing the first 80% right is often not that hard. It's the *remaining 80%* that's extremely difficult. Unfortunately an 80% "good enough" security solution may as well be a 0% solution from the perspective of an attacker. A weak link is all it takes to undo everything you've worked so hard to secure.

Comment: What kind of information am I exposing exactly? All web applications will have a login page how do routing layers mitigate this? Again, I may need to dive a bit deeper into this so, if these types of questions are easily explained in the framework I should probably go read up on them

Comment: If we're changing the context to educational, how would I go about this without using a framework? @tadman

Comment: Having `login.php` communicates two things immediately: First that it's probably a PHP application, and secondly that it's potentially if not probably homebrew. That makes it an ideal target for probing and testing. If I can `curl -I http://..../login.php` and get a bunch of version information I know it's going to be good, so I'll be motivated to continue probing. If you hide information, if you make it difficult to determine the back end, an attacker will be less interested, though that still won't entirely discourage them if they have a goal in mind.

Comment: @tadman gotcha that makes sense, as for that specific example I am hiding version information from being served up. I think you're overall point though, is that I may be covering holes now but in the future all it takes is one slip up.

Comment: I think you're unusually well qualified to evaluate any potential framework in terms of security and how it will fit your needs, so instead of blindly picking you can see what they're doing internally, if necessary, and make a sensible judgement that way. For example, look at [how Laravel handles authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) and see if it works for you. For other frameworks, where certain security features are optional, or must be configured specifically, you can always engage them properly.

Comment: Exactly. For example: The Meltdown/Spectre thing is still in the very early stages, it's more conceptual than an in-the-wild exploit, but the ramifications of it are astonishing. There's some talk in security circles that it may be necessary to randomize the names of form elements, or that today's CSRF techniques may need to be significantly strengthened if information can leak from the browser in certain ways. Applying an emergency patch to your framework is one thing, but having to solve it on your own, in a crisis, is really punishing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164711/discussion-between-shreddish-and-tadman).